# Update Manipulate[]'d plots when parameters change

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've been fighting with Mathematica's Manipulate function for the last few days for a project.

I'm working on tweaking assumptions and boundary conditions that go into a physical model.  For this, I want to be able to plot different equations and adjust the parameters and have the graphs update on the fly. Manipulate seems to be the perfect tool for the job -- except that I can't get it to work.  The plots won't update when the parameters are changed.

Basic example:

```
a =.;
b =.;
c =.;
func1[x_] := a*x;
func2[x_] := a*x^2 + b*x + c;
funcNamesList := {"Linear", "Quadratic"};
funcList := {func1[x], func2[x]}
Manipulate[
   Plot[function, {x, -5, 5}], {function,MapThread[Function[#1 -> #2],
    {funcList, funcNamesList}]}, {a, -5, 5}, {b, -5, 5}, {c, -5, 5},
    LocalizeVariables -> False
]
```

I can get, for example, `func1` to refresh by clicking `func1`, adjusting `a`, and then clicking`func1` again, but I'm hoping to have it update when I adjust `a`  because the real functions I'm using are rather temperamental with respect to their parameters.

-Because I'll be dealing with long functions that have different parameters, using a list of functions is useful.

**EDIT:**

In case it produces any ideas for anyone, here are some working examples of the individual components of what I want to do (from the Wolfram documentation):

Plot graphs and have them update when parameters are changed:

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}], {{a, 2, "Multiplier"}, 1, 4},
    {{b, 0, "Phase Parameter"}, 0, 10}
]
```

Note: This breaks when the function is taken outside:

```
func[x] := Sin[a x + b];
Manipulate[
  Plot[func[x], {x, 0, 6}], {{a, 2, "Multiplier"}, 1, 4},
  {{b, 0, "Phase Parameter"}, 0, 10}, LocalizeVariables -> False
]
```

Example of changing the function being plotted:

```
Manipulate[
   Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {f, {Sin -> "sine", Cos -> "cosine", Tan -> "tangent"}}
]
```

**Edit 2** 
Changed func2 from `a*x^2` to `a*x^2 + b*x + c` to reflect the fact that the functions may have different parameters.

**Edit 3** Added the tidbit I use to get nice names on the function buttons.

Comment: what do you mean "that have different parameters"? do they have different signatures?

Comment: Generally, you have to make  sure that the Manipulate control variables appear explicitly in Manipulate's body. So, its best to use the parameters in the function definition, so that they're visible to Manipulate.

Comment: If I execute your code the buttons are labeled a x and a x^2 not func1 and func2 as you state in the text.  Have you really posted your latest code?

Comment: @Sjoerd or `1.32x` and `1.32x^2` etc if you re-execute the `Manipulate`... Global state can be confusing!

Comment: So how would you like this to work? For instance, to have sliders for `a`, `b` and `c`, and simply ignore the `b` and `c` values when you are plotting the linear function? Or some other behaviour?

Comment: Sorry @acl, you caught me in the middle of an edit to accommodate your other question.  It should make more sense now.

Comment: You can use `Rule` instead of `Function[#1 -> #2]` in the `MapThread` (it may be easier to read)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems that prevent your `Manipulate` statement from working.

First, while the `Manipulate` variable `a` is global due to the `LocalizeVariables -> False` setting, the `Plot` variable `x` is not.  `x` is local to the `Plot` expression.

The second problem is that `Manipulate`, by default, assumes `TrackedSymbols -> Full`.  This means that only symbols that explicitly appear in the manipulated expression are tracked.  Note that `a` does *not* appear in the expression, so it is not tracked.

We can correct both problems thus:

```
a =.;
function =.;
func1[x_] := a*x;
func2[x_] := a*x^2;
funcList := {func1, func2}
Manipulate[
 Plot[function[x], {x, -5, 5}], {function, funcList}, {a, -5, 5}, 
 LocalizeVariables -> False, TrackedSymbols :> {a, function}
 ]
```

The changes are:

1. `funcList` was changed to `{func1, func2}`
2. The `Plot` expression was changed to `function[x]`, thereby referencing the local `x` variable.
3. The `Manipulate` option `TrackedSymbols :> {a, function}` was added.
4. `function` is initially unset.

Comment: Beautiful. As a new member, I'm not sure if this is the venue to ask, but if you have any pointers on finding issues like this, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: P.S. Is it redundant to +1 an answer and select it as the solution?

Comment: Rgarding the first request, perhaps I should be more specific.  I'm used to programming in C and C++. Between the compiler, gdb, and Valgrind, I have the tools necessary to figure out scopes and types of variables, to figure out when I'm using something that is undefined, or if I'm not passing an appropriate type to a method.  Without having Workbench, is there any way to get information of this sort in Mathematica?

Comment: ***Adding "function" to the TrackedSymbols list above is helpful. Without it, one must change a in order to have the second plot up date. ***

Comment: I incorporated your suggestion into my answer.  As for resources for learning about Mathematica's behaviour, check out [Mathematica Programming - An Advanced Introduction](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/) which discusses many of Mathematica's unusual elements.  Finally, it is common to both +1 and accept an answer.

Comment: should not the above be written as `TrackedSymbols :> {a, function}` and not `TrackedSymbols -> {a, function}` ?

Comment: @Nasser Yes, if we were not explicitly clearing `a` and `function`, then it would be be prudent to use `:>`.  It is a better choice in general use.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do this in a slightly different way:

```
func1[x_, a_] := a*x;
func2[x_, a_] := a*x^2;
funcList = {func1, func2};
Manipulate[
    Plot[Evaluate[function[x, b]],
        {x, -5, 5},
        PlotLabel \[Rule] funcList
    ],
    {function, funcList},
    {b, -5, 5}
 ]
```

but this may be unsuitable for what you want. Do your functions have different signatures?

EDIT: I've renamed the parameter to `b` to make it clearer that is it just a parameter being passed, as opposed to a global variable as you were using it.

Comment: They'll have different parameters at least.  So if I pass the parameters as arguments to the function, then yes.

Comment: Problem with this solution is the labels in the buttons have changed from describing the functions to just a bland label

Comment: In case it's useful to anyone coming by, that can be worked around by: declaring `funcNamesList := {"Linear", "Quadratic"};` and changing `{function, funcList}` to `{function, MapThread[Function[#1 -> #2], {funcList, funcNamesList}]}`.  (Although the original problem concerning different function signatures remains).

Comment: @Maberib can you give two example functions with different parameters? More productive than trying to guess :)