# Evaluation of Expressions inside Manipulate Statements

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have problems getting `Manipulate` to work with code assigned to variables that should be evaluated inside the `Manipulate` statement. Here is how it goes ...

```
test1={a,b,c};
Manipulate[test1,{a,0,10,.1},{b,0,10,.1},{c,0,10,.1}]
```

[image: Manipulate output 1]

So `{a, b, c}` are not updated. Ok, whatever, let's enforce the evaluation of test1

```
Manipulate[Evaluate[test1],{a,0,10,.1},{b,0,10,.1},{c,0,10,.1}]
```

[image]

Now it works. But if I want to plot the list of manipulated elements, like this

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[Evaluate[test1]],{a,0,10,.1},{b,0,10,.1},{c,0,10,.1}]
Manipulate[Evaluate[ListPlot[test1]],{a,0,10,.1},{b,0,10,.1},{c,0,10,.1}]
```

I end up with

[image]

in both chases.

I am aware of ['Evaluate Expressions inside Dynamic or Manipulate'](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/EvaluateExpressionsInsideDynamicOrManipulate.html) in Mathematica's documentation, but I am pretty sure that it does not provide a solution to my problem.

Comment: very similar question: [Update Manipulated plots when parameters change](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7126532/211232)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the problem is that `test1` is defined in terms of global variable `` Global`a ``, 
but the `a` defined in the manipulate is created by a `DynamicModule` and is thus local. This is what [acl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559318/acl) showed with his `Hold[a]` example.

Maybe the easiest way to fix this is to use `With` to insert `test1` into the manipulate:

```
Clear[a, b, c]
test1 = {a, b, c};
With[{test1 = test1}, 
     Manipulate[test1, {a, 0, 10, .1}, {b, 0, 10, .1}, {c, 0, 10, .1}]]
```

This way the `Manipulate` never actually sees `test1`, all it sees is `{a,b,c}` which it then goes on to correctly localize. Although, this will run into problems if `a,b,c` have been given a value before the `Manipulate` is run - thus the `Clear[a,b,c]` command.

I think that the *best practice* is to make all local variables completely explicit in the manipulate. So you should do something like

```
Clear[a, b, c, test1]
test1[a_, b_, c_] := {a, b, c};
Manipulate[test1[a, b, c], {a, 0, 10, .1}, {b, 0, 10, .1}, {c, 0, 10, .1}]
```

This avoids problems with the global vs local variables that you were having. It also makes it easier for you when you have to come back and read your own code again.

---

**Edit** to answer the question in the comments  *"I really would like to understand why Evaluate does not work with the somewhat nested ListPlot?"*. IANLS (I am not [Leonid Shifrin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/565518/leonid-shifrin)) and so I don't have a perfect Mathematica ([non](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html))[standard](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html) evaluation sequence running in my brain, but I'll try to explain what's going on.

Ok, so unlike `Plot`, `ListPlot` does not need to localize any variables, so it does not have the `Attribute` `HoldAll`.

Let's define something similar to your example:

```
ClearAll[a, test]
test = {a, a + 1};
```

**The final example** you gave is like

```
Manipulate[Evaluate[ListPlot[test]], {a, 0, 1}]
```

By looking at the `Trace`, you see that this first evaluates the first argument which is `ListPlot[test] ~> ListPlot[{a,a+1}]`
and since `a` is not yet localized, it produces an empty list plot. To see this, simply run

```
ListPlot[{a, a + 1}]//InputForm
```

to get the empty graphics object

```
Graphics[{}, {AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio^(-1), Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.}}, PlotRangeClipping -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}}]
```

As the symbolic values `a` have been thrown out, they can not get localized by the `Manipulate` and so not much else happens.

This could be fixed by still evaluating the first argument, but not calling `ListPlot` until after `Manipulate` has localized the variables. For example, both of the following work

```
Manipulate[Evaluate[listPlot[test]], {a, 0, 1}] /. listPlot -> ListPlot
Manipulate[Evaluate[Hold[ListPlot][test]], {a, 0, 1}] // ReleaseHold
```

The fact that `ListPlot` throws away non-numeric values without even the slightest complaint, is probably a feature, but can lead to some annoyingly hard to track bugs (like the one this question pertains to). Maybe a more consistent (but less useful?) behaviour would be to return an unevaluated `ListPlot` if the plot values are non-numeric... Or to at least issue a warning that some non-numeric points have been discarded.

**The penultimate example** you gave is (more?) interesting, it looks like

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[Evaluate[test]], {a, 0, 1}]
```

Now since `Manipulate` has the attribute `HoldAll`, the first thing it does is wrap the arguments in `Hold`, so if you look at the `Trace`, you'll see `Hold[ListPlot[Evaluate[test]]]` being carried around. The `Evaluate` **is not seen**, since as described in the [Possible Issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluate.html#306468591) section, *"Evaluate works only on the first level, directly inside a held function"*.  This means that `test` is not evaluated until after the variables have been localized and so they are taken to be the global `a` and not the local (`DynamicModule`) `a`.

It's worth thinking about how the following variations work

```
ClearAll[a, test, f, g]
SetAttributes[g, HoldAll];
test = {a, a + 1};

Grid[{
  {Manipulate[test, {a, 0, 1}], Manipulate[Evaluate[test], {a, 0, 1}]},
  {Manipulate[f[test], {a, 0, 1}], 
   Manipulate[f[Evaluate[test]], {a, 0, 1}]},
  {Manipulate[g[test], {a, 0, 1}], 
   Manipulate[g[Evaluate[test]], {a, 0, 1}]}
  }]
```

[image: brainpain]

Comment: +1 In a similar vein to the `With` solution, one could use `Manipulate[Evaluate@test1, ...]`.  However, I agree that the best practice is to use local variables.

Comment: @WReach: Yeah, but the `Evaluate` does not work in the `ListPlot` version of the question... (btw +1 to [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126532/update-manipulated-plots-when-parameters-change/7126947#7126947) to a nearly identical question)

Comment: I would like to emphasize that I've posted a minimal example in order explain the problem. In reality I am dealing with far more and changing parameters, so I don't want to write them down explicitly. +1 for the With solution (it is not a problem for me to Clear the variables). However, I really would like to understand why Evaluate does not work with the somewhat nested ListPlot?

Comment: @phantomas1234: I understand (and appreciate) that you produced a simple example that showed the behaviour you were having problems with. Hopefully my edit is close the to mark and can help explain what's going on.

Comment: @Simon: Awesome! 'The fact that ListPlot throws away non-numeric values ...': I totally forgot about that. Leonid could not have explained the question better than you did :-) Thank you for your extra effort.

Comment: I'd vote again for the IANLS bit if I could! "IANLS and neither is my wife"! (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python's_Life_of_Brian, for the uninitiated)

Answer (score 3):

Here is why it doesn't work:

```
Manipulate[
 {
  Hold[a]
  },
 {a, 0, 10, .1},
 {b, 0, 10, .1},
 {c, 0, 10, .1}
 ]
```

[image]

One may fix this in various ways. One is to simply define `test1` with the localized variables, like so:

```
ClearAll[test1, a, b, c];
Manipulate[
 test1 = {a, b, c};
 {
  test1
  },
 {a, 0, 10, .1},
 {b, 0, 10, .1},
 {c, 0, 10, .1}
 ]
```

and then eg

```
ClearAll[test1, a, b, c];
Manipulate[
 test1 = {a, b, c};
 ListPlot@test1, 
 {a, 0, 10, .1},
 {b, 0, 10, .1},
 {c, 0, 10, .1}
 ]
```

works.

If you prefer to define `test1` globally, this

```
ClearAll[test1, a, b, c];
test1 = {a, b, c};
Manipulate[
 test1,
 {a, 0, 10, .1},
 {b, 0, 10, .1},
 {c, 0, 10, .1},
 LocalizeVariables -> False,
 TrackedSymbols -> test1
 ]
```

works.

Comment: +1, but your first solutions have to `Set` `test1` every time a change is made. This isn't much of an overhead in this case, but it's probably best to avoid. Your 2nd solution has the "problem" that {a,b,c} become global variables, which might have unwanted consequences.

Comment: @Simon I agree with both your points (and by the idea behind your answer that "the right way" is to not use global variables but to inject the definitions literally with `With`). The idea here was to minimally alter the approach given in the question so that it works.